# WCF Service To Transfer 50K objects to client

Tags: .net, wcf

Even after reading so much about WCF, I am unclear what would be THE BEST approach to a very common scenario like the one below

The client is a windows desktop application which makes a call to a WCF service. (uses .NET TCP Binding, Per Session). The service needs to return more than 50K objects. *eg. List* - The Trade class has around 20 simple properties.

I am thinking to use 'TransferMode = Streamed' but I will lose the 'PerSession' instancing in that case.

I am looking for some design solutions and some best practices to such common scenarios.

Comment: You ask for the "best approach", but it will depend heavily on the situation. SO is not well suited for getting help with designing architecture (apart from more specific, practical questions related to that subject). PS. Are you sure you don't have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here? Why do you need to return 50K objects at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach here is to always make sure that you don't have to return such a big amount of data. The technique is called lazy loading - which means you load only that much data which the user has to interact with.

A good architect should consider the limitations of internet and different devices connected with the services and considering them, you should adopt the minimum available approach.